# How to get unique elements from an array and length of resulting array

Tags: java

I have an sorted array consisting elements (1,1,2,3,3,4). I want to get unique elements from this array and length of the resulting array.

Output array should consists (1,2,3,4) and size = 4.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java 8, you can do it in the following way:

```
Arrays.stream(arr).distinct().toArray();
```

**[DEMO](https://ideone.com/WwdoV1)**

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do here might be to just add your array elements to a sorted set, e.g. `TreeSet`:

```
int[] array = new int[] {1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4};
Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
for (int num : array) {
    set.add(num);
}
```

This option would make good sense if your code also had a need to work with a set later on at some point.